# patching java reflect calls using AOP

Tags: java, jboss, aop

I don't have a lot of experience with Jboss AOP and I'm just curious if it's possible to replace all calls like

```
Field f = foo.class.getDeclaredField("bar");
f.set(object, value);
```

with something like

```
Field f = foo.class.getDeclaredField("bar");
FieldSetCaller.invoke(f, object, value);
```

using Jboss AOP. `FieldSetCaller` is my own class.

I need to replace all Field.set calls on the fly, without recompiling the code. Some third -party code I even cannot recompile because I don't have the source.

I can achieve this using [java asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework and I'm wandering if Jboss AOP can do it as well.

Just for information - my code is running on Jboss server 4.3.0